# TypeError: tf__call() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mask'

Tags: python-3.x, function, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

```
def define_model():
    
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=X[0].shape)
    

    Dconv_1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, conv_kernel_size , strides=stride, dilation_rate=dilate)(inputs)
    Bnorm_1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(Dconv_1)
    Pool_1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=pool_kernel_size)(Bnorm_1)


    Dconv_2 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, conv_kernel_size, strides=stride, dilation_rate=dilate)(Pool_1)
    Bnorm_2 = tensorflow.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(Dconv_2)
    Pool_2 = tensorflow.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=pool_kernel_size)(Bnorm_2)


    Dconv_3 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, conv_kernel_size, strides=stride, dilation_rate=dilate)(Pool_2)
    Bnorm_3 = tensorflow.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(Dconv_3)
    Pool_3 = tensorflow.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=pool_kernel_size)(Bnorm_3)


    Dconv_4 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, conv_kernel_size, strides=stride, dilation_rate=dilate)(Pool_3)
    Bnorm_4 = tensorflow.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()((Dconv_4))
    
    
    fcn_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, conv_kernel_size , strides=stride)(Bnorm_4)
    Bnorm_5 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(fcn_1)
    unpool_1 = tfa.layers.MaxUnpooling2D(pool_size=pool_kernel_size,)(Bnorm_5)
    merge1 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([Bnorm_3,unpool_1], axis = 3 )
    
    fcn_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, conv_kernel_size , strides=stride)(unpool_1)
    Bnorm_6 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(fcn_2)
    unpool_2 = tfa.layers.MaxUnpooling2D(pool_size=pool_kernel_size)(Bnorm_6)

    

    fcn_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, conv_kernel_size )(unpool_2)
    Bnorm_7 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(fcn_3)
    unpool_3 = tfa.layers.MaxUnpooling2D(pool_size=pool_kernel_size , strides=2)(Bnorm_7)


    fcn_4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, conv_kernel_size , strides=stride)(unpool_3)
    Bnorm_8 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(fcn_4)
    
    outputs = Bnorm_8
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs , outputs)
    
    return model
```

I am trying to implement a research paper on document semantics structure extraction This uses a MultiModel Fully Convolution neural network.When I run the above model, it gives the following type of error. I am using tensorflow version 2.8 on windows os

Error:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for asking.

It would be great to paste the codes, instead of screenshot, it is a bit hard for people to debug/play around your codes

Comment: Thanks, Tim the necessary changes have been made.